# For a given vector field, how do I determine where F1 and F2 vanishes?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields

From my homework:

> Sketch the vector field F = (x−y)i +yj. Identify where F1 vanishes. Identify where
>   F2 vanishes.

I've sketched the vector field, but I don't know what is meant by identifying where F1 and F2 vanishes. How do I 'identify' where F1 and F2 vanish?

Comment: Do $F_1$ and $F_2$ refer to the $x$ and $y$ components of the field? If so, then this means for what points $(x,y)$ are the components zero? So $F_1 = 0$ when $x-y = 0$, and $F_2 =0$ when $y=0$. Can you describe these sets geometrically?

Comment: So (x - y) = 0 => y = x, so it's a line through the origin, which is also where y = 0 is. Okay, that makes sense. Thank you!